# Obtaining the CUDA include dir in C++ targets with native-CUDA-support CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, include-path

In CMake version 3.8, native support for CUDA as a language was introduced. When a project has CUDA as one of its languages, CMake will proceed to locate CUDA (e.g. it locates the nvcc binary).

As long as you only compile CUDA code - this is enough. But what if you want to compile a C++ target in that project? The CUDA includes are not `-I`'ed automatically, and `CMakeCache.txt` does not seem to contain the CUDA include path anywhere.

Do I actually have to run something `find_package(CUDA 9.0 REQUIRED)` even when CMake itself has already located CUDA? Or - can I obtain the include directory some other way?

Comment: @havogt: Yes, and you can make that an answer. But is there also a similar variable for the CUDA libraries?

Comment: on a normal CUDA install, the include location (dir) for CUDA libraries (i.e. their header files) is the same as the one for CUDA toolkit.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Yes, but I want to know what CMake knows, not make my own guesses which may be inconsistent with it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The **include directories**, which are used by the compiler set by `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER`, can be retrieved from the CMake variable [`CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html).

For getting the **libraries**, the best way is probably to use `find_library()` in combination with [`CMAKE_CUDA_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html).

Example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(MyProject VERSION 1.0)
enable_language(CUDA)

find_library(CUDART_LIBRARY cudart ${CMAKE_CUDA_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES})

add_executable(
    binary_linking_to_cudart 
    my_cpp_file_using_cudart.cpp
)
target_include_directories(
    binary_linking_to_cudart 
    PRIVATE 
    ${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
)
target_link_libraries(
    binary_linking_to_cudart 
    ${CUDART_LIBRARY}
)
```

This issue is also discussed on the CMake bug tracker: [Provide target libraries for cuda libraries](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17816).

---

**Update: CMake 3.17.0 adds FindCUDAToolkit**

Instead of doing `find_library()` manually, the best way as of CMake 3.17.0 would be to use the `CUDAToolkit` module.

```
find_package(CUDAToolkit)
add_executable(
    binary_linking_to_cudart 
    my_cpp_file_using_cudart.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(binary_linking_to_cudart PRIVATE CUDA::cudart)
```

For support with earlier CMake versions, you can ship the `CUDATookit` module file with minimal changes in your repository.

Comment: I think support for CUDA with MSVC was added only in 3.9 that's why I picked that.

Comment: Thank you for the update (which I happened upon accidentally...) this is much more convenient. Unfortunately, it'll be several years before we can assume CMake 3.17 is available on people's systems... :-(

Comment: Following my earlier comment: It is actually more reasonable than I believed to assume people have a newer CMake. The reason is that CMake binary distributions are quite flexible, and you rarely have to custom-compile. So getting CMake 3.17 (or by now, 3.21) is easy and painless.

Answer (score 2):

These days, with CMake 3.18 and later, you can get most of what you need by examining the targets provided by [`find_package(CUDAToolkit)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) - which you do need even if CUDA has located the CUDA compiler. But actually, you may just depend on one of those targets and *avoid* using the include directories directly.

PS - If you happen to use [cuda-api-wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers) (e.g. via `find_package(cuda-api-wrappers)`), it will take care of the dependencies for you.