# Can't find CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS in latest CMAKE

Tags: cmake, cuda

Since in CMAKE 3.10, CUDA macro is supported by default (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html).

But I can't find the variable CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(cmake_and_cuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

message(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

the errors are

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 10.0.130
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -- works
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (message):
  message called with incorrect number of arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tumh/code-samples/posts/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you haven't used the legacy CUDA build macros, whiy would you expect a legacy build variable like CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS to be set?

Comment: So How to find the cuda include directories in newer version of cmake?

Comment: That is a different question from what you initially asked -- but probably something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904431/681865

Comment: It looks like original question, but it couldn't get as much popularity like this later one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756562/obtaining-the-cuda-include-dir-in-c-targets-with-native-cuda-support-cmake

Answer (score 15):

Just use the `${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}`.

In all .cu src files, there is no need to manually add

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}),
```

because CMake will do it for you.

But for .cpp src files, if you need to `include <cuda_runtime.h>`, you must manually add

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})
```

in your CMakeLists.txt.